# Update multiple rows

Tags: sql

How to update multiple rows using id as primary key in a table with a single query ??

i have collection of id's say 23,25,26  . i have to update todo_deleted column as checked for all the three rows with ids 23,25,26

I need a query which should be very efficient.. Post ans if u know.. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5):

Like this, using `IN`:

```
 UPDATE `myTable` SET `todo_deleted` = 1 WHERE `id` IN (23, 25, 26)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMN = NEW VALUE
WHERE ID IN ( 23, 25 ,26 )
```